# finding first non empty td starting from the current tr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a tabel like this

```
time   a     b    c    b
9:30        38         
9:00       
8:30  2.7        20
8:00        32   21    77
7:30             
7:00             28
```

i am converting this to an array with jquery by looping verticaly true each row. the result looks like this

```
[{ type: a , time: 9:30 , value:  } ,
 { type: a , time: 9:00 , value:  } ,
 { type: a , time: 8:30 , value: 2.7 } ,
 { type: a , time: 8:00 , value:  } ,
 { type: a , time: 7:30 , value:  } ,
 { type: a , time: 7:00 , value:  } ,
 { type: b , time: 9:30 , value: 38 } ,
 ...
]
```

the problem i have is that i need to convert the empty value to the first non empty value if there is one in the current column. 
for example the the output needs to be:

```
[{ type: a , time: 9:30 , value: 2.7 } ,
 { type: a , time: 9:00 , value: 2.7 } ,
 { type: a , time: 8:30 , value: 2.7 } ,
 { type: a , time: 8:00 , value: n/a } ,
 { type: a , time: 7:30 , value: n/a } ,
 { type: a , time: 7:00 , value: n/a } ,
 { type: b , time: 9:30 , value: 38 } ,
 { type: b , time: 9:00 , value: 32 } ,
 ...
]
```

im am struggling to achieve this with jquery/javascript. 
here is the fiddle what i have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/L9bd8pad/

Comment: I think your description is incomplete.  E.g., what would you expect c/9:00 to hold?  There are multiple values in that column.

Comment: Is it jquery/java or jquery/javascript?

Comment: c/9:00 would hold the same value as c/8:30 because that is the last know value. 
the table only fill in the values if there where any changes since the last know record.

E.g. the column c has to look like this: 
9:30 = 20
9:00 = 20
8:30 = 20
8:00 = 21
7:30 = 28
7:00 = 28

Comment: @chsdk It looks like jQuery+JavaScript. I don't think there is a jQuery+Java library. I would be rather surprised if there is, but I might be wrong.

Comment: sorry corrected this in the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop the column backwards, from bottom to top, and save the non-empty value from a below cell. Then, when an empty cell is encountered, set the value to the previous non-empty value. This is demonstrated below:

```js
//Only do the following when the document loads:
$(function() {
    //converting colspan="2" to two <td></td>
    $('tr').each(function () {
        $(this).find('td').each(function () {
            if ($(this).attr('colspan')) {
                $("<td></td><td></td>").insertBefore($(this));
                $(this).closest("td").remove();
            };
        });
    });

    //var for knowing how many times we need to loop
    countTD = $(".data-table tr:eq(1)").children('td').length;

    arTX = [];

    for (i = 1; i < countTD; i++) {

        //var for knowing first td
        countDate = i - 1;

        //Store the value of the last cell we visited:
        var lastValue = null;
        //This is the array we are going to concatenate arTX with:
        var newArr = [];

        //looping true each cell vertically backwards, from bottom to top 
        $($('.data-table tbody tr').get().reverse()).each(function () {
            $(this).find('td:eq(' + i + ')').each(function () {

                value = $(this).text();
                date = $(this).prevAll(":eq(" + countDate + ")").text();
                type = $('.data-table thead tr:eq(0)').find('th:eq(' + i + ')').text();
                //If we do not have a valid value but lastValue is valid, set valid to lastValue so we can use the value from a previous cell of the same type.
                if (!value && lastValue) value = lastValue;
                //Otherwise, value must be valid, so set lastValue to value.
                else lastValue = value;

                //Push this cell into newArr:
                newArr.push({
                            "value": "" + value + "",
                            "date": "" + date + "",
                            "type": "" + type + ""
                        });

            });

        });
        //Since we traversed the above cells backwards, reverse newArr and then concatenate it with arTX:
        arTX = arTX.concat(newArr.reverse());
    }
    console.log(arTX);
});
```

```css
body {
    font-size: 10px;
}
td {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="data-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Datum</th>
            <th>a</th>
            <th>b</th>
            <th>a</th>
            <th>b</th>
            <th>c</th>
            <th>b</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>10:00</td>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
            <td colspan="2"></td>            
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>9:30</td>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>9:00</td>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>8:30</td>
            <td>2.7</td>
            <td>38.6</td>
            <td>2.1</td>
            <td>37.9</td>
            <td>1.7</td>
            <td>37.9</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>8:00</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>38.9</td>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>7:30</td>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: perfect! didnt know of the reverse function. Thank you verry much

Comment: No problem! Glad to help!